# OrderBy Sum in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

How would I go about ordering a sum in Laravel

Currently, using

`Auth::user()->activities()->groupBy('attempts_id')->sum('points');`

Will only give me the first row. I need to order by that sum in descending order and grab the first item.

Using `->get()` at the end results in an error:
`Call to a member function get() on a non-object`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Auth::user()
    ->activities()
    ->groupBy('attempts_id')
    ->orderByRaw('SUM(points) DESC')
    ->first();
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That combined with a raw select did the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes if you need the actual value in the result you have to use a raw select :)